# how to get the rendered width of internationalized button text in GWT?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

While testing our app with a new set of translations, I found that the translated text for some of the buttons are significantly wider than the english. The result is that the button text wraps to a 2nd line, which is either cut off by the button, or floating below on a 2nd line. It seems like I need to get the rendered width of the text in order to dynamically resize the buttons, assuming there's space in the layout for a wider button.

Is there a way to get the width of the rendered text of a button?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a monospace font for the buttons (why not do so, actually?), and render it using CSS `en` / `em` / `ex` units, you cant really predict the text width, only make an educated guess.